# How to display all three different numbers(Work, Home, Cell) for client in on column over the rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have very unique requirement of displaying phone number from 3 different column into one column

I am getting following result from my sql query which give me contact number for all active client right now in the system.

[image]

I would like to convert all different column of phones into one column.

[image]

Please help.

Here is my query from which I am getting above result

```
    select 
       c.CLIENT_ID as "Client No",
    c.[HOME_PHONE] as "Home Phone",
    c.[WORK_PHONE] as "Work Phone",
    c.[WORKEXT] as "Work Ext",
    c.[CCELL] as "Cell Phone",
    '' as Assignment_ID,
    'Office-Paris’ as "Office",
    '1F65781E-78F6' as Owner
FROM CLIENTS c
left join    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by CLIENT_ID
                    order by startdate desc) as rn
        ,       CLIENT_ID
        ,       STATUS
        ,STOPDATE
        ,       DEPT_ID
        from    CLTSTATES
        where   STARTDATE <= '2016-09-08'and DEPT_ID='R0000000001'
        ) h
on      c.CLIENT_ID = h.CLIENT_ID
        and h.rn = 1 -- Only last row
where   h.STATUS = 'A' 
order by c.CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: I asked the same question but who needs this result don't care about that which phone number is which. All they need is three phone number in three rows in front of same client and sorry as well as extension.

Comment: Please use unpivot for desired result.

Comment: Hmmm, Thanks for that, I can use Unpivot on simple table/query. Since my query is already kind of complex, how to do Unpivot on top of this? PLEASE guid.

Comment: It doesn't matter how complex your source query is, just put all the code in  place of your source table in the `unpivot`

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick reply. @iamdave you are right, but the thing is I already have 8 different queries like above to cover all possible options different offices, different, service etc. and this is all for migration so probably it's too much time consuming to create table or view and then do unpivot on top of that.

Comment: Since this is for one time only I am just gonna use 4 different number into 4 different queries one by one under one column heading and paste into excel and give it team, since I have to do this in hurry!! but excellent option guys. Thanks again iamdev, BhatiaAshish!!

Answer (score 2):

May this work, please test because i don't have data -

```
select
    [Client No],
    [Phone],
    [Assignment_ID],
    [Office],
    [Owner]
from (
        select 
            c.[CLIENT_ID] as "Client No",
            c.[HOME_PHONE] as "Home Phone",
            c.[WORK_PHONE] as "Work Phone",
            c.[WORKEXT] as "Work Ext",
            c.[CCELL] as "Cell Phone",
            '' as Assignment_ID,
            'Office-Paris' as "Office",
            '1F65781E-78F6' as Owner
        FROM CLIENTS c
        left join    (
                select  row_number() over (
                            partition by CLIENT_ID
                            order by startdate desc) as rn
                ,       CLIENT_ID
                ,       STATUS
                ,STOPDATE
                ,       DEPT_ID
                from    CLTSTATES
                where   STARTDATE <= '2016-09-08'and DEPT_ID='R0000000001'
                ) h
        on      c.CLIENT_ID = h.CLIENT_ID
                and h.rn = 1 -- Only last row
        where   h.STATUS = 'A'
) x
unpivot
( Phone for different_location in ([Home Phone], [Work Phone], [Work Ext], [Cell Phone])
) u
order by CLIENT_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ClientNo, phone = HomePhone, AssignmentId, Office, Guid From Blah Blah
union all 
Select ClientNo, phone = WorkPhone, AssignmentId, Office, Guid From Blah Blah
union all 
Select ClientNo, phone = CellPhone, AssignmentId, Office, Guid From Blah Blah


-- Etc.
```